# How to change dns in godaddy to point to windows azure linux vms?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, dns, centos

I have 2 linux vm in 2 separate cloud services in windows azure, so both vms have an external public ip, one has centos for cpanel and another one has ubuntu for magento.

We are ready to change dns, but its unclear which ips or nameservers we have to use.

anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your domain is being hosted by godaddy as you said, so would recomment creating a 'A' Record and pointing that to the public ip of your vm respectively.

Thus if your VM1 has public ip say 88.66.77.55 and you would like to point yourdomainname.com to your vm , just add 'A' Record and point yourdomainname.com to 88.66.77.55.

Using Cname is also correct but it increases load time which is obvious because of DNS lookup of your vm public dns + that Cname routing.

So adding 'A' record is better in terms of speed.

Comment: Only if you make sure you reserve the IP address of the machine, which wasn't available on Azure for most services when I posted my answer. Otherwise on reboot it will change and your site will go down.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to associate the existing domain name you own with a Azure cloud service.
Typically, this is the guidance to follow: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentioned by Simon gives you all the details but just to give the quick overview

Your Azure website has a name such as

```
myname.cloudapp.net
```

You still need to host or have your domain provider host your DNS.

The best way is to then create a CNAME of subdomain.yourdomain.com to myname.cloudapp.net

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7921/adding-or-editing-cname-records?locale=en

Azure has just recently released reserved IP addresses but they are only configurable by Azure Powershell at the moment and not in the portal (planned to be released in the portal soon)

The easiest way is the CNAME approach. You may consider the Reserved IP address approach if DNS lookup time on your client side is of a major concern due to speed requirements.